# ag-grid performance issue in firefox

Tags: ag-grid

We are using ag-grid version '17.1.0'.

We have observed metrics, time taken for render grid in firefox is more compare to chrome.

### logs captured:

**Chrome : 'BalancedColumnTreeBuilder: 2064ms'**

**Firefox: 'BalancedColumnTreeBuilder: 10766ms'**

```
  BalancedColumnTreeBuilder.prototype.createBalancedColumnGroups = function (abstractColDefs, primaryColumns) {
    console.time('BalancedColumnTreeBuilder');
    // column key creator dishes out unique column id's in a deterministic way,
    // so if we have two grids (that cold be master/slave) with same column definitions,
    // then this ensures the two grids use identical id's.
    var columnKeyCreator = new columnKeyCreator_1.ColumnKeyCreator();
    // create am unbalanced tree that maps the provided definitions
    var unbalancedTree = this.recursivelyCreateColumns(abstractColDefs, 0, columnKeyCreator, primaryColumns);
    var treeDept = this.findMaxDept(unbalancedTree, 0);
    this.logger.log('Number of levels for grouped columns is ' + treeDept);
    var balancedTree = this.balanceColumnTree(unbalancedTree, 0, treeDept, columnKeyCreator);
    this.columnUtils.depthFirstOriginalTreeSearch(balancedTree, function (child) {
        if (child instanceof originalColumnGroup_1.OriginalColumnGroup) {
            child.setupExpandable();
        }
    });
    console.timeEnd('BalancedColumnTreeBuilder');
    return {
        balancedTree: balancedTree,
        treeDept: treeDept
    };
};
```

huge difference between chrome and firefox executing time of BalancedColumnTreeBuilder code.

Comment: That's interesting.... What about ie? Just being curious

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to speed firefox up?